# Why is glTexImage2D() backwards?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm using `glTexImage2D()` to create a texture. The texture is from a simple array of pixels.

I'm specifying pixels with the format `RGBA`. However, OpenGL seems to expect the pixels to be formatted `ABGR` (RGBA backwards) in calls to `glTexImage2D()`.

The short of it is:

```
GLuint CreateTexture()
{
    int w = 16, h = 16;
    // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    // Supposed to be:         0xrrggbbaa    !!
    // But actually            0xaabbggrr    !!
    vector<GLuint> rgba(w * h, 0xaaff0000);//!!
    // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

    GLuint texId;
    glGenTextures(1, &texId);  CHECK_GL;
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);  CHECK_GL;
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);  CHECK_GL;
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);  CHECK_GL;
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);  CHECK_GL;
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &rgba[0]); CHECK_GL;
    return texId;
}
```

[The full to a running program you can try out is here](https://gist.github.com/superwills/525521e6e62c7e5a616fb4ef85773c2d).

Comment: See [Reverse Color in Texture](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Reverse_Color_in_Texture)

Answer (score 1):

`GL_BGRA` is probably what your GPU really wants anyway and it reads as `0xAARRGGBB` on little endian machine if you want to be sloppy and know that you will never use anything but little endian machine.

Of course I'd always recommend to just have a type colour that is array of 4 bytes and converting it using bitshifts instead of caring about endianness at all in the first place.

Unless you're doing something very specific and you can explain why, there's no reason to bother yourself with that. There's machines with mixed endianness, are you going to write code that also detects it and acts accordingly? Let your compiler do it for you, it should be your last concern. We invented programming languages precisely so we don't have to think about any of these things.

Lets say the format you'll give to OpenGL is `GL_BGRA`
Your chosen user format is `RGBA`.

```
unsigned char rgba[4] = { 0x00, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33 };
GLuint colour = static_cast<GLuint>(rgba[2]) << 0  | // B is first element
                static_cast<GLuint>(rgba[1]) << 8  | // G is second element
                static_cast<GLuint>(rgba[0]) << 16 | // R is third element
                static_cast<GLuint>(rgba[3]) << 24;  // A is fourth element
```

- `colour` is now `0x33001122` on little endian
- `colour` is now `0x22110033` on big endian
- `colour` is now `0x11223300` on malbolge endian
- `colour` is now `0x13132020` on insanity endian

But do you NEED to know that?

Comment: Are there QEMU targets for malbolge & insanity?

Comment: @genpfault I'm not aware of any exotic targets for QEMU but for example on a PDP-11, that's essentially how a 32bit integer is stored, as its a 16bit little-endian architecture. They decided that two little-endian words in big-endian order represent a 32bit integer, such as`0xBADC`, instead of `0xDCBA` that you'd expect on a little-endian machine. Emulator can store data however it wants as long as it adheres to the rules of how data is interpreted and expected to be observed by a program, so unless you get a real machine I don't think its going to be that interesting.